# How to determine the end of block comments on Pugjs (jade)?

Tags: pug

How to add an element to a parent element with block comment before the child elements??
I tried to do that but it gives me two choices :

1- make the child element a sibling element! which I don't want to

```
body
    main
        .main-container#main
             // this is a comment will apper on html file
             //- this is a comment will not apper on html file 
        p hello
```

2- the child element will be a part of the block comment if I gave it 2 indents and if I gave it one indent it throws an error!!

```
body
    main
        .main-container#main
             // this is a comment will apper on html file
             //- this is a comment will not apper on html file 
            p hello
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments and the paragraph element should all be at the same indentation level as children of their parent element:

```
body
  main#main
    .main-container
      // this comment will appear in compiled HTML
      //- this comment won't appear in compiled HTML
      p hello
```

Note that the first forward slashes of the comment syntax are at the same level as the `p`.